# Do players reveal their sort order for Forecast?

Tags: pandemic-on-the-brink

The instructions are not really clear on some of the nuances of the game, particularly the bioterrorist scenario.

When playing the Forecast event card, do the players have to divulge the order they are sorting the cards to the bioterroist? Or can they do so secretly?

Comment: Hi Bytor47, and welcome to board games stack exchange. We ask one question per question here, or only additional questions if they're inseparably related to the first. Accordingly I've removed the second (unrelated) question; please feel free to ask it separately. You can access it in your question's revision history, found by visiting the [edited X time ago](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/45489/revisions) link underneath your question.

Answer (score 3):

With the forecast event you can chose to discuss or not discuss the what the cards where that you drew and what order you put them back in. However if you do discuss any of that information you can't keep it from the bio-terrorist.

[Rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/PandemicOnTheBrinkExp-rules.pdf)

> The Bio-Terrorist may listen to the other players as they discuss their plans
>   and cards, but should not interrupt them on their turns. The non-Terrorist
>   players may not hold private discussions nor pass notes to each other.

I would note that it is possible to lie about the information you got from the card but I would question how useful it would be to lie to your teammates and it could end up hurting you more in the long run.